# ICommand vs RoutedCommand

Tags: wpf, mvvm, icommand, routed-commands

Let's have a button `Command` property bound to a custom command.

When should I implement `ICommand` and when derive from `RoutedCommand`? I see that **RoutedCommand implements ICommand**.

In which case could I need to implement an `ICommand`? 
What about MVVM model? Which one suits better for this purpose?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

As you have noticed the [`RoutedCommand` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.routedcommand.aspx) is an implementation of the `ICommand` interface, its main distinction if that its function is similar to that of a `RoutedEvent`:

> The Execute and CanExecute methods on a RoutedCommand do not contain the application logic for the command as is the case with a typical ICommand, but rather, these methods raise events that traverse the element tree looking for an object with a CommandBinding. The event handlers attached to the CommandBinding contain the command logic.
>
> The Execute method raises the PreviewExecuted and Executed events. The CanExecute method raises the PreviewCanExecute and CanExecute events.

In a case when you don't want the behavior of the `RoutedCommand` you'll be looking at your own implementation of `ICommand`.  As for the MVVM pattern I can't say that one solution, it seems that everyone has their own methodology.  However, here are a few approaches to this problem that I've come across:

- [Using RoutedCommands with a ViewModel in WPF](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/VMCommanding.aspx)
- [Relaying Command Logic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx#id0090030)
- [Simple Command](http://marlongrech.wordpress.com/2008/11/26/avoiding-commandbinding-in-the-xaml-code-behind-files/) (almost identical to Relay Command but worth reading)

Comment: Thank you. I think the most important think to realize is that they traverse the tree looking for an object with CommandBinding. As in MVVM I want to avoid CommandBindings, I decide for ICommand.

Comment: Routed commands move the useful tasks from the object triggering the command, up in the visual tree, to allow sharing. In a routed command CanExecute and Execute methods only raise pairs of routed events, they do nothing else and ignore if events will eventually be handled. Usually a CommandBinding is attached to some ancestor to handle events and perform the meaningful work. In non-routed commands, CanExecute and Execute do all the work, but splitting the work using routed events allows to delocalize and share a part of the work, e.g. to manage multiple commands with a single CommandBinding.

Comment: As @PaN1C_Showt1Me already mentioned, as the routed events are a matter of view (with CommandBinding being attached to some view element), a routed command is not easy to use in MVVM, [a non-routed command can be defined in the view model](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/18199.event-handling-in-an-mvvm-wpf-application.aspx) instead.

Answer (score 30):

The only thing I would add to Rich McGuire's answer is that RoutedCommands (and their more prevalent descendant [RoutedUICommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.routeduicommand.aspx) have to be wired up with event handlers to work correctly.

Most MVVM implementations I have come across attempt to leverage binding against the ViewModel and thus the ViewModel (and not the View) owns the CanExecute/Execute logic.

In contrast, the event handlers move that burden to the View.  The handling can then be propagated to the ViewModel, but this means a slightly higher degree of coupling between ViewModel and View (casting + method call, etc.).