# Difference between Delegatecommand, relaycommand and routedcommand

Tags: c#, mvvm, command

I'm confused about command pattern. There are so many different explanations about the commands. I thought the code below was delegatecommand, but after reading about the relaycommand, I am in doubt.

What is the difference between relaycommand, delegatecommand and routedcommand. Is it possible to show in examples that have relevance to my posted code?

```
class FindProductCommand : ICommand
{
    ProductViewModel _avm;

    public FindProductCommand(ProductViewModel avm)
    {
        _avm = avm;
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return _avm.CanFindProduct();
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        _avm.FindProduct();
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
        remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
    }

}
```

Comment: have you done a google search.. look at the examples here try the code and apply it to what you have.. 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff654132.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.mvvm.relaycommand.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.routedcommand.aspx

Comment: Yes, it did not help so much

Comment: I would suggest doing a google search on command pattern's on google then

Comment: @DJKRAZE: i have done it, that is why i'm being doubt with my posted code, is it delegatecommand or relaycommand? There are many different explanations.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Your `FindProductCommand` class implements the [`ICommand`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.icommand%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) interface, which means it can be used as a [WPF **command**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752308.aspx#Anchor_0). It is neither a `DelegateCommand` nor a `RelayCommand`, nor is it a `RoutedCommand`, which are other implementations of the `ICommand` interface.

---

**`FindProductCommand` vs `DelegateCommand`/`RelayCommand`**

Generally, when an implementation of `ICommand` is named `DelegateCommand` or `RelayCommand`, the intention is that you don't have to write a class that implements the `ICommand` interface; rather, you pass the necessary methods as parameters to the `DelegateCommand` / `RelayCommand` constructor.

For example, instead of your entire class, you could write:

```
ProductViewModel _avm;
var FindPoductCommand = new DelegateCommand<object>(
    parameter => _avm.FindProduct(),
    parameter => _avm.CanFindProduct()
);
```

(Another, perhaps greater benefit than the savings in boilerplate code -- if you instantiate the `DelegateCommand` / `RelayCommand` within your viewmodel, your command has access to the internal state of that viewmodel.)

Some implementations of `DelegateCommand` / `RelayCommand`:

- [Microsoft Prism DelegateCommand reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff654132.aspx)
- [WPF Tutorial implementation of `ICommand` called `DelegateCommand`](http://wpftutorial.net/DelegateCommand.html)
- [Another implementation](http://relentlessdevelopment.wordpress.com/2010/03/30/simplified-mvvm-commanding-with-delegatecommand/) also called `DelegateCommand`
- The [original implementation of `RelayCommand`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx#id0090030) by Josh Smith

Related:

- [Relay/ICommand vs DelegateCommand -- Differences](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16988250/111794)

---

**`FindProductCommand` vs `RoutedCommand`**

Your `FindProductCommand` will execute `FindProduct` when triggered.

WPF's built-in [`RoutedCommand`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.routedcommand.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396&cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1) does something else: it raises a [routed event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742806.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) which can be handled by other objects in the visual tree. This means you can attach a command binding to those other objects to execute `FindProduct`, while attaching the `RoutedCommand` itself specifically to one or more objects that trigger the command, e.g. a button, a menu item, or a context menu item.

Some related SO answers:

- [MVVM Routed and Relay Command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/650010/mvvm-routed-and-relay-command)
- [WPF ICommand vs RoutedCommand](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1135983/111794)