# Relay/ICommand vs DelegateCommand -- Differences

Tags: c#, wpf

As far as I can tell the below code can be changed from Relay/ICommand Command to Delegate command and still bind the commands the same way!  If I am wrong what are the differences and uses of each.

```
private DelegateCommand something;
public DelegateCommand Something
```

Here is the full implementation

```
private RelayCommand something;
public ICommand Something
{
    get
    {
        if (something == null)
            something = new RelayCommand(SomethingMethod, CanSomething);
        return something;
    }
}

private bool CanSomething(object parameter)
{
    //just for readability return true
    return true;
}

private void SomethingMethod(object parameter)
{
    using (DatabaseContext context = new DatabaseContext())      
    {
        try { }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            throw new ApplicationException(string.Format("Something {0} to {1}", file, directory), ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Which frameworks are you using to get your `RelayCommand` and `DelegateCommand` implementations?

Comment: I think they are just implementation of ICommand interface to implement WPF Commanding. They are used by different frameworks. Also you should take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14180688/difference-between-delegatecommand-relaycommand-and-routedcommand

Comment: @Reed The framework is 4.0

Comment: @KeyboardFriendly What libraries/references are you using.  Those types aren't part of the .NET Framework, they're part of a third party MVVM "Framework" (library).

Comment: Sorry was checking new to MVVM, using NuGet.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Neither `DelegateCommand` nor `RelayCommand` exist in the framework itself.  They are provided by third party libraries.

Both are an implementation of [`ICommand`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms616869) which works by accepting a delegate and using that to provide the `ICommand` implementation.  As such, both classes have the same intent, and work in basically the same manner.

As for differences - there may be some subtle diffferences, depending on which framework you're using.  For example, Prism's [`DelegateCommand<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff654132.aspx) also has a concept of [`IActiveAware`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.practices.composite.iactiveaware.aspx), which is used for building composite commands.