# Using Commands in WPF using the MVVM pattern

Tags: c#, wpf, model-view-controller, mvvm, command

I am faced with a problem that might be known by other developers and I am trying to figure it out and understand it well. It doesn't have to be directly connected to MVVM/WPF, it can also be connected to other methodologies like MVC and MVP .

Lets assume I have a shop cart Model that has its own Service, addItem and deleteItem Methods and calculates the price of the shop cart etc.

Now in my View I display this shop cart and when I want to show the total sum of the shop cart I click on a button to trigger the method that take cares of this.

Here comes the problem: How can I bind the Method (or Command) to the Button? I know that I have to use `ICommand`, but by using this interface I kind of break the rules of responsibility separation. How can I implement, without break the rules of the MVVM pattern.

[image: Example:]

Comment: you will implement it in ViewModel of the VIew

Comment: Look at implementation of ICommand https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.icommand(v=vs.110).aspx and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1135983/wpf-icommand-vs-routedcommand

Comment: Using `ICommand` in ViewModel is not a violation of MVVM pattern, as commands are a presentation concern and hence belong to the ViewModel. @Domysee pointed it already out, in the command you just relay it to the service layer. Remember, that you may rise a notification or set the new price to a property that does rise the notification it its setter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you call *PresentationModel*, is the *ViewModel* in WPF, which is the *DataContext* of the View.
This ViewModel holds an instance of `ShopCart`. It also holds the commands, so that the view can bind to them.
The command, lets name it `CalculatePrice` should just invoke the `calculatePrice()` method of the `ShopCart`.

The question is, how do you define it that way:
Well, I like using [`RelayCommand`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx#id0090030), which allows you to define commands using lambda expressions.

So then you can have a property `public RelayCommand CalculatePrice`, which you define in the constructor:

```
public ViewModel(){
    CalculatePrice = new RelayCommand(param => this.ShopCart.calculatePrice());
}
```

That way, you can bind the CalculatePrice command to the button, which then executes `ShopCart.calculatePrice()`.

Answer (score 2):

If I understood correctly, in your view you display a set of ShopCarts, and you want to be able to call the `ShopCart.calculatePrice()` method. I would say, what you need to do, is to store the ICommand object in your ViewModel, and bind the ShopCart to the `CommandParameter` property. This way, you will receive the ShopCart as the parameter of the `CanExecute` and `Execute` methods.